# WPF ItemsControl data binding - adding extra initial controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I have the following XAML for a databound items control to show a list of groups, with a label and button to add a new group appearing first:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Groups" />
    <Button x:Name="btnGroupAdd" Click="btnGroupAdd_Click" Content="+" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="_groupList" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                </WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="3" BorderThickness="1">
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="_groupEnabled" Click="GroupEnabled_Click" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="_groupName" Text="{Binding Path=Group.Name}" ></TextBlock>
                        </CheckBox>
                        <Button x:Name="_deleteGroup" FontStyle="Normal" Click="DeleteGroup_Click" />
                    </WrapPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

With a small number of groups, everything appears on one line.

> Groups +  Group1  Group2  Group3

When I add more groups, the wrap panel containing the items wraps, but the initial label and button to add a new group is on its own row, with the databound groups starting on the next row.

> Groups + 
>   Group1  Group2  Group3  Group4
>   Group5

I can understand why this is happening, as the wrap panels are nested. My question is: how do I include the first label and button in the inner wrap panel so that they aren't on a row on their own?

> Groups +  Group1  Group2  Group3 
>   Group4  Group5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy with this:

> Groups + Group1 Group2 Group3
>                   Group4 Group5

Then I would suggest using an outer `Grid` and an inner `WrapPanel`. Otherwise, your options are:

1. Include the other controls (`Label` and `Button`) or a view model reprenting those controls in the collection you're binding to.
2. Write your own `Panel`.

Comment: Thanks Kent, it does help. I'll have a look at the grid, as it seems easiest. I don't think I can add the controls to the collection, as it's being deserialized from an XML file.  

I guess the next question is how to write my own panel...